# Looping within functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to repeat a certain piece of code with a two second interval inbetween, how would I do so?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
      kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
      if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
        $(document).unbind('keydown',arguments.callee);
            $('.preview').attr('style', 'background: #'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16) + ';');
      }
    });
```

with this being repeated:

```
$('.preview').attr('style', 'background: #'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16) + ';');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loop"?

Comment: for loop? while loop? recursive loop?

Comment: Where is the loop? A loop is formed by `for`, `while`/`do..while` statements.

Comment: By loop I mean infinitely repeat the attribute change every two seconds

Comment: It's probably better to describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: take a look at **[setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)**

Comment: You need to clean this question up and use the word "Repeated"  and time :)

Comment: Which part of the `$('.preview')` are you looping over? Are there multiple elements?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use a conjunction of

`setTimeout()`

with a recursive call to the function and the proper base case.

you can keep an argument as the total time elapsed and use that to do what you want. You can also use

```
setInterval()
```

That should put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Simple loops in javascript, jquery not required...

```
// simple for loop
var array = [1,2,3,4];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]);
}

// simple while loop
var i = 0;
while (i < 4){
    console.log(array[i]);
    i++;
}

// simple object iteration
var object = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 };
for (var attribute in object){
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(attribute) === true){
        console.log(object[attribute]);
    }
}
```